# Jackson start deserialization two levels down

Tags: java, jackson

I have an awkwardly constructed json file like this:

```
{
"clientByClientId" : {
  "123" : {
    "clientId" : "123"
     "moreFields" : "moreData"
   }
  "456" : {
    "clientId" : "456"
     "moreFields" : "moreData"
   }
 }
}
```

As you can see, the top two levels of this json are superfluous. What is the best way to deserialize this into a collection of `Client` objects? I tried using online json to pojo tools, but they ended up generating classes called "123" and "456". Ideally, I'd like to use Jackson, but am open to other solutions.

Comment: The only flaw I see in your json string are missing commas. Can you double check with the proper commas in place ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small note: your JSON is malformed, as it is missing a few commas. Once those are added, then this will work for you.

First off, you'll need a class to represent a `Client`:

```
public class Client {
    private final int clientId;
    private final String moreFields;

    @JsonCreator
    public Client(@JsonProperty("clientId") int clientId, 
                  @JsonProperty("moreFields") String moreFields) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.moreFields = moreFields;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Client[clientId=" + clientId + ", moreFields=" + moreFields + "]";
    }
}
```

Now, you just need to create your `ObjectMapper` and iterate over the elements of your `clientByClientId` map, which can be done with the following:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(json).get("clientByClientId");
Map<Integer, Client> clientMap = objectMapper.readValue(node.traverse(),
        new TypeReference<Map<Integer, Client>>() {});
System.out.println(clientMap.values());
```

The output of this code is:

```
[Client[clientId=123, moreFields=moreData], Client[clientId=456, moreFields=moreData]]
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! And yeah my mistake about the commas - working too much with yaml has spoiled me.

Answer (score -1):

I think something like this should work:

```
   public class Body {
    public ClientByClientId clientByClientId;
}

public class ClientByClientId {
    public Map<String, Client> clientMap;
}

public class Client {
    int clientId;
    String moreFields;
}
```

This should put your top-level ids as the key in the map.